# Why does my "plugin" execute only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my first attempt to write a jQuery plugin, this one is supposed to fade out the body, switch class, then make the body reappear and let the user switch class back. Unfortunately at this point it can't switch class more than once. How to fix it?

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.flashClass= function(classId, element){

        element="body"; //overriden for testing purpose
            $(this).click(function() {
                $(element).fadeOut("slow", function() {
                    $(element).toggleClass(classId);
                });
                $(element).fadeIn("slow", function() {
                    $(element).scrollTop(height);
                });
            });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

EDIT:

At the end of the day, It turned out that I've pasted the wrong snippet with scrollTop callback of undefined variable *height*. After  removing it and switching `.click` to `.on` , function works like a charm. However I am still interested why it worked only once.

Comment: What makes you think it "can't switch class more than once?"  What happens the second time it's called?

Comment: why do you get element parameter if you override it with `body`???

Comment: Where are you changing classes?!

Comment: It worked once because all the fadein/out code had been run when the missing `height` caused the error. Once the error is hit, no further javascript code will be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the live() or on(), like following :

```
 $(this).on('click',function() {...
```

Instead of

```
 $(this).click(function() {...
```

Comment: `live()` is deprecated. Use `delegate()` or `on()` instead

Comment: @Pointy `$(this).click(function() {` ...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `delegate` is deprecated as well, afaik.

Comment: @Johan Not deprecated yet, as it's the best method of attaching events to dynamic elements in <1.7: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/. I'm sure it will happen soon though as 1.7+ becomes more widely used.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan oh duhh ... I need to clean my glasses :-)  However in this case I doubt that that's the issue, as `this` is already an element on the page; in fact if all you have is the jQuery `this` you can't use the bubbled event APIs anyway because you don't necessarily have a selector to work with.